# Excel VBA to select a navigation Tab on a Webpage

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

Stuck in an area of a webpage and can't seem to figure out how to select any one of the navigation tabs.
I've already gotten through coding for the ID, password and a couple of other screens to get to this one.
Tried just about every combination of "GetElementBy" that exists (I think) but to no avail.
The Tabs aren't in their own frame as far as I can tell.
Here's the HTML Code for the tabs.
If anyone can help with a quick way of selecting one, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(1)}" class="active">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(1)">
            Prototypes
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(2) || isSet(3)}">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(2);">
            Devices
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(4)}" ng-show="!IsInitialRelease">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(4)">
            Notices
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(9)}" ng-show="!IsInitialRelease">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(9)">
            Assembly Details
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(7)}" ng-show="!IsInitialRelease">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(7)">
            Waivers
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(8)}" ng-show="!IsInitialRelease">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(8)">
            Notifications
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(5)}" ng-show="!IsInitialRelease">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(5)">
            Permits
        </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isSet(6)}">
        <a href="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setTab(6)">
            &nbsp;Search&nbsp;
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code, it looks like an Angular site that you are trying to automate using IE VBA Automation.

We can notice 2 things from the source code.

1. Active tab has `class="active"` attribute set for the `li` tag.
2. Each `li` tag contains the hyperlink with an Angular click(ng-click) event.

In this scenario,

1. We can first try to loop through `li` tags and remove the `class="active"` attribute.
2. Find the desired tab by matching the hyperlink text and click the hyperlink then set the `class="active"` attribute for that tab.

these steps may help you to select the desired tab.

Sample code:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://Your_Web_page_address_here..."

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
     
    Set elems = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("li")
    
    For Each elem In elems
     '  Debug.Print (elem.getAttribute("class"))
        If (elem.getAttribute("class")) = "active" Then
        
            elem.removeAttribute ("class")
    
            Exit For
        End If
    Next elem
    
    For Each elem In elems
      '  Debug.Print (elem.innerText)
        If (elem.innerText) Like "*Devices*" Then
            elem.Children(0).Click
            elem.setAttribute "class", "active"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next elem
    
    'ie.Quit
End Sub
```

You can try to debug the sample code to see how it is working step by step, and further, you can try to modify it based on your requirement.

Comment: I hadn't seen that method of removing the class="active" attribute and searching for the innerText like you did here. I'm sure that I'll run into this again in other places on this site so your explanation will come in real handy. P.S. Your code worked like a charm. Much appreciated.